# what is the subnet mask for class D addresses?

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip

iam finding subnet mask for class A,class B, class C addresses but am not finding any subnet mask for an IP 239.192.140.22 ;how to find subnet mask for class D IP addresses?

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost: ***classful routing is dead, and has been for over 20 years (since 1995)!***

The former Class D addresses are multicast addresses, and they don't really use masks since each multicast group, represented by a single address, is subscribed to individually. When configuring multicast routing (different than regular IP routing), there are instances where you may use a mask to indicate a range (dependent on the multicast routing device), but the mask used depends solely on the size of the range and not on any arbitrary concept like class.

The former Class E addresses are reserved, so there is not really a mask concept for them, either.